# Do I use "also" in a correct way?

Tags: word-usage

I was typing an email and reviewing it. I cannot decide if I used *also* correctly.
Can anyone help me?

> "I am pleased to attach herewith my application form, for your kind consideration. **Also**, the documents are attached includes certificates as requested.
>
> Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Note that this question could be (or future questions would be) much improved if you explained **why** you think you may have used a word or phrase incorrectly. Do you think it might be wrong to use it at the start of a sentence? Are you unsure of what the word means? The more you make us speculate, the less likely it is that you'll get answers that meet your need.

Comment: Your sentence needs correcting. **Also, documents are attached, including certificates as requested.** You would only use **the documents** if you had previously referred to them or the recipient knew which documents you were referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer validates the position of 'also' in the text you quoted, but that text is wrong in various ways that are nothing to do with the placing, or use, of 'also'. You could have said 'the attached documents also include the certificates, as requested'.

'the documents are attached' is wrong in this context. You could say 'the documents that are attached' and that would not be wrong. The usual way of expressing that idea would be to say 'the attached documents'.

It has to be 'include' not 'includes' because 'documents' is a plural subject of the verb. If you had said 'the attachment ...' then you could use 'include' because 'attachment' is singular.

Comment: There's a typo. The last 'include' should be 'includes'.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you used it correctly.

According to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/also-as-well-or-too) dictionary,

> *Also* occupies different positions in a sentence.
> We use *also* in front position to emphasise what follows or to add a new point or topic:
> *It’s very humid. **Also**, you can easily get sunburnt.*

Therefore, you are emphasizing, in your phrase, that certificates are included in the email.